# Using Bessel function in a shader in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, shader, bessel-functions

I'm trying to access Bessel function J0 in a shader in Unity.
I haven't found any built-in function that does the job.
I have calculated 10 000 points of the J0 via python and stored them in a .txt
But I don't have any idea how to deal with it.

Comment: rather implement the function itself into the shader and let it calculate on the fly?

Comment: There is no explicit form of this function. How can I implement it?

Comment: `I have calculated 10 000 points of the J0 via python and stored them in a .txt` sounds like you have at least an implementation in python.. so could you not port it into a shader?

Comment: I don't know how to do this ^^'